# php duplicate a file in other folders

Tags: php, duplicates

Is there a way I could use php to make root file to look like its also in other folders too.

For example I have index.php in root folder and I want it to be like that when I access index.php then it could also behave as its in all the folders and subfolders too

When I execute index.php then it will also execute in all folders and subfolders too

**Please understand my question by the example below**

index.php is in root and I have different folders in root as well so when I access the index.php through browser then it will also execute in other folders

```
http://mysite.com/index.php will also behave as if its in sub folder too
http://mysite.com/folder1/index.php
http://mysite.com/folder2/index.php
http://mysite.com/folder3/index.php
```

index.php is not in these folders but it must execute in these folders too at the same time

I think its not difficult to understand through above examples.please answer accordingly

**Update 2**

Here is the index.php code

It scans the folders "files" "images" "txt" "related" and get the files in each folder and then it writes to the includes.php (in root)

```
$path = array("./files/","./images/","./txt/","./related/");

$path2= array("http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."/files/","http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."/images/","http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."/txt/","http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."/related/");

$start="";

$Fnm = "./include.php";

$inF = fopen($Fnm,"w");

fwrite($inF,$start."\n");



    $folder = opendir($path[0]);

    while( $file = readdir($folder) ) {

           if (($file != '.')&&($file != '..')&&($file != 'index.htm')) {

                $folder2 = opendir($path[1]);

                $folder3 = opendir($path[2]);
                $folder4 = opendir($path[3]);

                $imagename ='';

                $txtname ='';
                $related ='';

                while( $file2 = readdir($folder2) ) {

                    if (substr($file2,0,strpos($file2,'.')) == substr($file,0,strpos($file,'.'))){

                        $imagename = $file2;

                    }

                }
while( $file4 = readdir($folder4) ) {

                    if (substr($file4,0,strpos($file4,'.')) == substr($file,0,strpos($file,'.'))){

                        $related = $file4;

                    }

                }


while( $file3 = readdir($folder3) ) {



if (substr($file3,0,strpos($file3,'.')) == substr($file,0,strpos($file,'.'))){



                        $txtname = $file3;



                        $fh = fopen("/home3/socialb8/public_html/mysite.info/player/txt/$txtname", 'r');

                        $theData = fread($fh, filesize("/home3/socialb8/public_html/mysite.info/player/txt/$txtname"));

                        fclose($fh);



                    }



                }

                closedir($folder2);

                closedir($folder3);
                closedir($folder4);

            $result="{\nlevels: [\n{ file: \"$path2[0]$file\" }\n],\nimage: \"$path2[1]$imagename\",\ntitle: \"$file\",\ndescription: \"$theData\",\n 'related.file':'$path2[3]$related'\n},\n";

            fwrite($inF,$result);

           }

    }

    fwrite($inF,"");

    closedir($folder);



fclose($inF);
```

Comment: This is a *bizarre* use-case. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If the user requests one file and all other files should be executed as well, why not simply inlude them? Or do you just want that: No matter which URL the user calls, it's always the same file that gets executed? Than you should take a look into `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: You could also use .htaccess files to reroute the user to the correct directory, ie /demos/ reroutes to /demo/ or something. Just as another option, since I believe mod_rewrite, might be a better solution.

Comment: @insertusernamehere well the problem is I do not want the user to access other sub-folders.user is only allowed to access the main index.php and when user access the main index.php then at the same time it must execute in all folders too

Comment: I think your actually looking at using mod_rewrite to make it look like the same page runs from different locations on your website.

Comment: @thatidiotguy please see the above comment.mod_rewrite is not an option for me as it doesnot fullfills my requirements

Comment: @Sammaye mod_rewrite is not an option as the users will not access the subfolders,they only access the main index.php so when they do it will also execute on subfolders too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340001/deny-direct-access-to-all-php-files-except-index-php That should get you started

Comment: @Sammaye this question has nothing to do with my question.I do not want to deny access to subfolders

Comment: what does index.php *do*? that might help trying to work out how it needs to run in the other directories.

Comment: `well the problem is I do not want the user to access other sub-folders.user is only allowed to access the main index.php` that question tells you how to do that, the duplication thing....well I have no idea why your doing that but you can use exec to cp

Comment: @Stu I have updated index.php code in my quesion

Comment: @Sammaye Yes user only access index.php but it also must execute in other folders too please see the example I have given in the question

Comment: could you not add the directories you want to scan into the index.php? i.e. `$path = array("./files/","./images/","./txt/","./related/","./folder1/files/","./folder1/images/","./folder1/txt/","./folder1/related/");`?

Comment: @Stu Ok good idea but I do not want to specify each folder so is there a way I could add a variable in the path so that when I create new folder then I do not have to include that folder,because there are 100s of folders

Comment: @user1613566 Yes it was supposed to solve ONE of your problems, I have no idea though what you mean by `execute`? You have gone from executing all php files to including all files in folders....wtf...

Comment: I supose you could cycle through all the directories and then see if the folders in the `$path` array exist there?

Comment: @Stu Yes can you tell me a way how I could cycle through all the dir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to cycle through the directories and see if each of those directories contains one of the directories listed in the `$path` array you could use something like:

```
function readDirs()
{
    $path=array('images','etc...');
    $dirHandle = opendir('./');
    while($file = readdir($dirHandle))
    {
        if(is_dir($file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..')
        {
            $dirHandle2 = opendir($file);
            while($file2 = readdir($dirHandle2))
            {
                if(in_array($file2,$path))
                {
                    // do what you need to do
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
readDirs();
```

That will cycle through all the directories in the root folder and see if they contain a directory listed in the `$path` array, if so you can pop your code in the `// do what you need to do` statement.

Hope that helps!