# Deny access to all .php files except root index.php

Tags: regex, .htaccess

This is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340001/deny-direct-access-to-all-php-files-except-index-php/1607587) but with one caveat: I want to deny direct access to all files named index.php below the root directory.

Allow:
/index.php

Deny:
/application/views/settings/index.php

I know I can use PHP to look for a defined constant or variable, but is it possible to achieve this using .htaccess only? This is what I have so far:

```
##
# Disallow direct access to files.
#

<FilesMatch "^(.*)\.php$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "^index\.php$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Adding a third `FilesMatch` to deny `"^(.*)/index/index\.php$"` does not work.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There may be a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: It is for an MVC application. All controllers have a corresponding directory inside `/application/views`, with the default view always being named "index".

It is not a big deal – I can always name it "default" or something else – but I would just like to know if it is possible to this with .htaccess.

Comment: So you want to prevent the index.php's being called directly? The way most frameworks do this is, they define a constant somewhere, then add a check for that constant in every file they don't want called directly: `if (!defined("CAN_RUN")) die ("This file can't be called directly.");`

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just thought this could be done with .htaccess alone, and save a few lines of code in each file.

Comment: I would tend to put this in the PHP file for clarity's sake. It's a pretty kludgy htaccess rule; plus it won't work if you ever use a web server different from Apache, or if Apache is not configured with `AllowOverride All`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it with `<FilesMatch` or `<Files>` directive alone: you need to combine them with `<Directory`. For example:

```
<Directory /var/www>
  <FilesMatch "\.php$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "^index\.php$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/*>
  <FilesMatch "\.php$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
  </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

The catch here is that you should edit `httpd.conf` or similar files, as `<Directory>` directive cannot be used in `.htaccess`.

If you can't update `.conf` files and `.htaccess` is the only way around, you would have to copy the shown rule in each directory's `.htaccess`, I suppose. Whether or not it's better than using `if(defined(...))` trick, is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sL3eV0)

`(?<![^\/])\/index\.php`

A quick regex, you may want something more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to prevent the index.php's being called directly?

The way most popular web apps do this is, they define a constant somewhere, then add a check for that constant in every file they don't want called directly:

In the main file that can be called directly, and that includes the other index.php files, do:

```
define ("CAN_RUN", true);
```

In every sub-file that you don't want called directly:

```
if (!defined("CAN_RUN")) die ("This file can't be called directly.");
```

Comment: Don't the most frameworks separate application files from public scripts instead (so the former are inaccessible from `/public` directory)?

Comment: @raina77ow that's indeed the very best way to go where possible. I meant to say most popular *web apps* like WP, of which most don't have this separation - at least not properly.