# Deny all exept one folder and one file with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My project structure is:

```
-application
-lib
-public
-index.php
-.htaccess
```

.htaccess now is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I need to restrict access to all folders exept `public` and `index.php` file. How to do it?

I tried to add `Deny all` to my `.htaccess` and `Allow all` into `public` folder, but my `index.php` become inaccessable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a `RewriteRule`. Use the following instead:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1

<Files /index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>

<Directory "/public">
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: See also for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251500/deny-access-to-all-php-files-except-root-index-php

Comment: Did you write this yourself?

Comment: It is adapted from two websites, there are even some sites which can generate this easily

Comment: @Xavjer but my index.php is an `FrontController`, so all requests should be redirected there. How to save this behavior?

Comment: Okay, that is an other case, check http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/redirect-all-pages-to-indexphp-except-one-page adapt it to your public folder and it should work