# How to access a file from URL using Curl

Tags: php, linux, apache, curl, permissions

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      root        514 Jan 15 04:03 curl.php
-rw-r----- 1 root      root       1344 Feb  5 02:09 dbm-config.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      root       5149 Feb  5 02:19 mysql-connectivity-status.php
```

Here, Am accessing the file "mysql-connectivity-status.php" from url like
 `http://<ip>/html/DB-Monitoring/mysql-connectivity-status.php`.

In `mysql-connectivity-status.php` I have called the file `dbm-config.ini`. While am accessing  via URL am getting the following Warning.

```
Warning: parse_ini_file(/var/www/html/DB-Monitoring/dbm-config.ini): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/DB-Monitoring/mysql-connectivity-status.php on line 113
```

So, I don't want to change the permission for the `dbm-config.ini` But how to I access the file using URL?

Comment: Do you happen to know if you're running SuPHP or PHPExec on your server? You should be able to find out via phpinfo(). I might just change the permissions of the file to 644 and then block direct access to the file via htaccess so PHP can still access it. [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340001/deny-direct-access-to-all-php-files-except-index-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> -rw-r----- 1 root      root       1344 Feb  5 02:09 dbm-config.ini

The file can be read from and written to, by the user root `rw-` and read from by the members of the group root `r--`

If you access the php file using curl, this is executed most likely with your webservers user and group which is not `root:root`

That's why php can't read the ini file.
I recommend to move the file out of your document root so it can't be accessed directly from the web, then change the owner to your webserver user and group

determine the username php is executed with

```
ps aux | grep "httpd" # apache environment
ps aux | grep "php"   # php fastcgi environment 

chown user:group dbm-config.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your webserver cannot access that file. If you cannot fix that you cannot access it remotely through that webserver. :)

Wild guess, since I don't know what you're using:

```
chown root:apache dbm-config.ini
chmod g+r dbm-config.ini
```

might help. That will set the owning group of the file to apache and give the group read access. IF your webserver is apache and that is the correct group that it is using this might help.