# Allow a specific PHP file to access a hardened wp-content folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

1) My wp-content is hardened with a .htaccess file containing this code:

```
<Files *.php> 
deny from all
</Files>
```

2) I want (need) to authorize `xml-sitemap-xsl.php` Otherwise I get this error in my error log: `client denied by server configuration: /home/user/mysite.net/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/css/xml-sitemap-xsl.php, referer: http://mysite.net/sitemap_index.xml`

3) I think I should add the following code but I’m not sure if it’s the right code nor where to place it:

```
<Files "xml-sitemap-xsl.php">
Allow from all
</Files>
```

The thing I want to avoid is a conflict between the deny and allow commands.

Thanks,

P.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has not much to do with Wordpress and I am not an expert regarding `.htaccess`, but I believe that what your file is doing is not denying access to your directory by all `.php` files, rather, **denying access to all the `.php` files inside the directory.**

The `<Files>` directive is used to add specific rules to specific files and, as far as I know, it *cascades*.

Considering your comment, this should do the trick

```
<Files *.php> 
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files "xml-sitemap-xsl.php">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your feeback. I appreciate it. Then my question should be: in Wordpress, how to denying access to all the .php files inside a directory, except for specific files and/or from specific client?

Comment: This is not really a wordpress issue. I think using the .htaccess you posted should do the trick, before `Allow from all` put an `Order allow,deny`. I edited the answer.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I’ve implemented your solution. For future reference, where should I ask such a question? At the Webmasters StackExchange?

Comment: Honestly I am not sure: Stackoverflow itself seems a good place. I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

see: [Deny direct access to all .php files except index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340001/deny-direct-access-to-all-php-files-except-index-php/1607587#1607587)

Comment: Too bad I could only check one. The reference you provided allowed me to confirm the solution see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11711319/348567). Thanks!