# Deny access to .php files apart from the server itself

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I write a .htaccess script that prevents the user from running .php files in a certain directory and it's child directories?

I would need to be able to include the php file from the servers index.php or other files though, basically I want to enable to the server to to include the php files from a certain directory but, if the user were to type in the specific URL, it would deny access.

Comment: Keep them outside `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

Comment: You have something of a dichotomy in your title. The user requesting them *is the server*

Answer (score 1):

This could do the trick

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
   Deny from all
<FilesMatch>
```

Also, see the answers to this question: [Deny direct access to all .php files except index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340001/deny-direct-access-to-all-php-files-except-index-php)

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, fixed it.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, I was mistaken - it is possible to use File directive in .htaccess. I'v just looked up Apache documentation and checked <Files "*.php"> variant - it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this:

If I want a user to access a file, say `members.php` or `index.php`

```
<?php
    $GLOBAL_PAGE="page name"; //set the 'visible' flag
    include_once 'headers.php'
...
?>
```

In `headers.php`:

```
<?php
     if(!page_is_authorized($GLOBAL_PAGE))
         //redirect to a valid page
         header( 'Location: index.php' );
     ....
?>
```

where `page_is_authorized($s)` checks `$s` against a list of valid values.

I know this doesn't use .htaccess rules as you requested but I usually don't have access to that file so there goes. It's portable too!

Comment: +1 about the portability. This helps if for some reason using `.htaccess` is forbidden on the server.