# How to block access to all .php except index.php in root folder (via .htaccess)?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

> Note: This question has been asked before several times, but the answers are really bad, totally wrong and/or do not fit the above scenario (because there are several files called *index.php*). If you like, see [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340001/deny-direct-access-to-all-php-files-except-index-php)].

I want to block direct access to all .php files in the *application* folder (see file structure image) via the .htaccess file in the root folder. There are some solutions for this on the web, but they miss one thing: They don't work **if there is more than one file named index.php** (which is a realistic scenario like the screenshot shows, see the file in the view/xxx/ folder):

#### Question: How to block access to all .php files, except the index.php in the root folder ?

[image]

Comment: Sorry if you've tried this, but have you tried moving everything outside of the document root and having `index.php` reference those files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/application - [F]
```

The `[F]` option instructs it to issue a *403 Forbidden* response on all matching URLs.

Or add a separate .htaccess file in `/application` containing just:

```
deny from all
```

Or in your Apache vhost definition:

```
<Location /application>
  deny from all
</Location>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me? Does this work for any one? index.php in sub directories are still accessible.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to **Niels Keurentjes** [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20694431/1114320) I would like to extend his solution according to my .htacces that uses some very common rewriting patterns (as a lot of people might run into the same problem):

When using URL rewrite rules, then the line `RewriteRule ^/application - [F]` has to be **at exactly that place**. It will not work if the line is placed before or below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# The new line, blocking direct access to every file in /application and deeper
RewriteRule ^/application - [F]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Hmm, this does not seem to work like i thought... It also blocks files that are NOT in the *application* folder.