# htaccess prevent direct .php files except index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, utf-8

I want to prevent direct .php file access. This below 2 lines works fine

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php - [F,L]
```

But, it won't open index.php file. I want to prevent direct .php file access except **index.php** file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deny direct access to all .php files except index.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340001/deny-direct-access-to-all-php-files-except-index-php)

Comment: Even images, css, javascript too ?

Comment: @frz3993 Only PHP files

Answer (score 1):

Add a condition to not apply the rule to the specific file:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)$
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent direct access to all `.php` files except `index.php` you can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[?/] [NC]
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ - [F,L,NC]
```

You need to use `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable for this. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+).css$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+).js$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /deny/ [nc]
```

Access to files "CSS" and "JS" and "index.php" will be there. Other requests will be redirect to "Deny" folders.