# Deny direct access to all files except one PRETTY URL with get parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to deny direct access to all files, except one: `go.php`.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340001/deny-direct-access-to-all-php-files-except-index-php) question, but in my case it doesn't work because I send also a GET parameter.

That means that all files should be denied, except when trying to go to `www.domain.com/go.php?code=xyz123`.

My code now:

```
Order Allow,Deny
deny from all
allow from [my IP here]

<FilesMatch "go.php">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT 1**

I updated the code to:

```
<Files go.php>
Allow from all
</Files>
```

Now it does allow if the url is `domain.com/go.php?code=123`. The thing is that I use pretty URLs with this rewrite condition:

```
RewriteRule ^go/([a-z0-9]+)$                /go.php?code=$1
RewriteRule ^go/([a-z0-9]+)/$               /go.php?code=$1
```

So, the above Files code does not work if the url is `domain.com/go/123`. How to fix this?

Comment: You _could_ implement that based on a `RewriteCond` looking for the GET parameter and a `RewriteRule` redirecting everything else to an error document. But this is a strange concept, access control via a GET parameter...

Comment: I don't mind that people would access `go.php` becuase by the php file, is there's no `code` GET parameter, you just get redirected to the 404 page. So basically what I need is the code to write in the `FilesMatch`, becuase just `go.php` does not work with the GET parameter.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Please see my question edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is just one specific file, you don't need `FilesMatch`, but can use [`Files`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#files) instead

```
<Files go.php>
...
</Files>
```

---

Rewriting from `/go/123` to `/go.php?code=123` is a classic. You capture the part for the query string and use it in the substitution

```
RewriteRule ^go/(.+)$ /go.php?code=$1 [L]
```

---

I didn't expect `<Files go>` or `<FilesMatch go>` to work, because "/go/123" isn't a file in the strict sense.

So despite my ignorance an additional

```
<Files go>
Allow from all
</Files>
```

works.

As an alternative, you can use [`If`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#if) and check for the requested URL path

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m,^/go/,">
Allow from all
</If>
```

Comment: This one works, but doesn't work with my pretty url format. I have: `RewriteRule ^go/([a-z0-9]+)$                /go.php?code=$1`. If I go to `domain.com/go.php?code=123` it does work, but doesn't work with `domain.com/go/123`.

Comment: These are two different and independent things. 1. `Files/FilesMatch` is for restricting the access control to a specific (set of) files 2. `RewriteRule` is for rewriting from one URL to another.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but I meant to ask another thing. the Files code you gave me allow access to `domain.com/go.php?code=123` but not if the url is a pretty url: `domain.com/go/123`. I just edited my question to explain my problem better.

Comment: I just tried this combination in my test environment, and I have no such problem. When I enter `/go/123`, it calls the go.php script as expected. What doesn't work in your environment, and what is the output?

Comment: @AvielShomron - You might want to be more specific in your question to begin with, instead of moving the goal post after you get a working answer to the initial question.

Comment: @OlafDietsche, It takes me to the 403 Forbidden Page, and says: `You don't have permission to access /go/123 on this server.`

Comment: @AvielShomron Ok, you're right, it seems I messed up my first test.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
<FilesMatch "go|go.php">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Thank you all!