# Apache 2.4 how to redirect exact php file only - but NOT normal queries

Tags: apache, redirect

It seemed to me simple but I still did not find an answer.

Under Apache 2.4 I need redirect all requests to
http://example.com/data/request.php to http://example.com/info.html
That's simple with

```
RedirectMatch .*/request.php http://example.com/info.html
```

But I need to leave all normal queries intact (like below)

```
http://example.com/data/request.php?id=26561
```

but with RedirectMatch rule above all normal queries also redirects to

```
http://example.com/info.html?id=26561
```

Thx for any ideas to try,

Comment: You need to use a rewrite rule with rewrite conditions and test if `%{QUERY_STRING}` if empty or not. There's plenty on the subject already.

Comment: Not tested (no access to Apache) but perhaps precede the RewriteRule with `RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" ""`

Answer (score 0):

Thx for hint from @Capsule above - may be somebody needs an exact answer against my example

For correct redirect we have to use

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?request.php$ http://example.com/info.html? [L,R]
```

It redirects only exact

```
http://example.com/data/request.php
```

but leave intact queries like

```
http://example.com/data/request.php?id=26561
```